# OnTouch Change Background Image

Tags: android, background, touch-event

I am working on changing the background image of my app when the user presses a quarter of the screen.  I have posted what I have done so far below, but is not working.  I am also not sure how to reference the png picture that I have saved into my resource folder.  Thanks.

```
    public class TouchtwoActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   float x,y;
   TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textv);
   View vv;
         @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eight); 

    vv.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();
  if(x > getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2) 
  {
      changeImage(); 
  }
    return true;        
}

public void changeImage()
{
     getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("name of png from drawable));
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

First add the view (vv) u created as child of a layout u have created in the XML. Then set height and width to the view (vv) using layout params.

Or u can create a view in XML and get it using findViewById just like u did to the text view.Then write **vv.setOnTouchListener(this);**

Then in onTouch try

**getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background_2);**

Comment: So I have a linear layout and within in it just a textview. I add vv to the linear layout? Do I do that within the XML file or the Java file?  Something like LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myname) then lay.addView(vv);?

Comment: U can either do it by adding a view in xml and View vv = (View)findViewById(R.id.view_name);vv.setOnTouchListener(this);

or  LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myname) then lay.addView(vv);(This case u have to set height and width to the view before adding the view to layout)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background_2);
```